# Password Self-serve Active Directory via LAMP environment

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, active-directory, ldap

I would like to be able to change active directory passwords via a Linux/Apache based webpage.  This would be a self serve web page for the user.  I have SSL-LDAP setup on the Active Directory to make this happen.  Is there any project or code out there that will do this?

I've looked at this [phpadadmin](http://www.james-lloyd.com/phpadadmin/) and I cannot get it to work.  I think this is for IIS/php/mySQL

Another thing to note is I would like the user to authenticate to change their own password.  The product/service should not need a privileged account to run.

Thanks
Keith

Comment: Active Directory uses some sort of proprietary hashing. I dropped a similar project, unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any pre-built solutions, but you could pretty easily create a web page which shells out and executes 'adtool'.

See a nice overview here:

http://www.ghacks.net/2009/08/02/manage-your-active-directory-from-linux-with-adtool/

Answer (score 2):

phpadadmin is just a wrapper for adLDAP.
http://adldap.sourceforge.net/

Both of which require the php-ldap extension be installed.

Answer (score 1):

Check out some of the PERL Win32:OLE modules or just any LDAP module for that matter.  I once wrote a perl CGI web app for doing the same thing using the Win32:OLE module but AD is just LDAP.

Answer (score 1):

For a paid solution, [myPassword](http://www.namescape.com/Products/myPassword/Default.aspx) from Namescape handles this pretty nicely.

Comment: Looks like this is a webpage solution.  However, this does not fulfill my requirements.  I'm looking for something that runs in a Linux/Apache environment.

Answer (score 1):

checkout this [link](http://yajith.blogspot.com/2007/12/squid-ldap-and-active-directory.html), it should be possible to get phpldapadmin to tie in with an Active Directory server to get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

The [LDAP Tool Box Self Service Password](http://ltb-project.org/wiki/documentation/self-service-password) does exactly this. And  it is open source!

Answer (score 1):

From the LDAP toolbox Self Service Password docs for Active Directory: Due to PHP LDAP API limitations, changing password as user is not possible. You need to change it as manager.

Comment: Editing your answer to add a link to those docs would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[CorendalDirectory](http://www.corendal.com/products/corendal-directory) is FREE and a pretty sophisticated LAMP and Web-based AD management tool.

It has the self-service password changing you are looking for and even user and group template based object creation, too.

Answer (score 0):

[Self-service password](http://ltb-project.org/wiki/documentation/self-service-password) from the [LTB-project](http://ltb-project.org/) is a simple open source PHP application to allow users to change their own password on any LDAP server. It is compatible with AD.